# How to fix vagrant variable not defined?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Please suggest what is the error in this.
I am getting error as ws2 variable not defined even though it is defined.

https://github.com/ukreddy-erwin/openstacklogs/tree/master/04-06-2020

Answer (score 0):

I've used the files provided through your github and everything is working for me, there was no issues faced (i've terminated after the ws2 machine started since this means everything worked correctly), i've also attached an image showing that things actually worked.

[Powershell output after vagrant up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM6SY.png)

Comment: Yeah, I tried on a different machine today and it is working, on my machine old version of terraform is there, does it make any issue? It is just minor version version channge

Comment: I don't think there's any sort of relation between vagrant and terraform so i doubt that terraform caused anything.

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong..this issue fixed once I update vagrant